# Cannot resize checkbox when dynamically adding checkboxes to form

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, I'm trying to dynamically add checkboxes to a tab sheet on a form.  I've tried the AutoSize property but some of my text is too long. the `x.Size.Width` is returning:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Froms.Control.Size'
>   because it it not a variable

I've searched through a lot of forums and can't seem to find an answer.  Any ideas?

```
foreach (CheckBoxes i in main)
            {
                CheckBox x = new CheckBox();
                x.Text = i.Data;
                x.Checked = i.Condition;
                x.Location = new Point(main_start_location_x, main_start_location_y);
                x.Size.Width = 570;
                tabControl1.TabPages["main_checklist_tab"].Controls.Add(x);
                main_start_location_y += 40;
            }
```

Comment: Try setting the size using a `Size` object, i.e. `x.Size = new Size(...)`

Comment: instead of calculate and set the `Location` for each of the checkboxes, put them in a layout panel like `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the size of a control by using the control's `Width` and `Height` properties or the `Size` property, but not the `Width` and `Height` of the `Size` property, since that is passed by value and will have no effect.

1) `Control.Size = new Size(width, height);`

or

2) `Control.Width = width;`

Comment: Thank you - I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
x.Size.Width = 570;
```

Use this:

```
x.Width = 570;
```

if you want to set the whole size at once, do this:

```
x.Size = new Size(570, 20);
```

or this:

```
x.Width = 570;
x.Height = 20;
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you for the quick response! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before :)